# Inputs and Outputs in Python?

Tags: python, input, output

I am looking at some python challenges and the questions ask to take an input and produce an output. I don't really understand the concept of input and output. Is the your code supposed to read the input and produce an output? I've pasted one of the questions from the challenge, would be great if someone couple explain. Thanks

================================

**- Example Question**

Read two integer numbers R and C from the standard input and then print R lines with C asterisks (*) each.

Example (R=3, C=5):

```
******
******
******
```

Example (R=2, C=10):

```
**********
**********
```

Input

The first line will contain an interger R. The number of lines to print.

The second line will contain an integer C. The number of asterisks to print in each line.

R, C will be at most 20.

Output

Print a rectangle of R lines and C columns.

================================

**- Answer**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
R, C = map(int, raw_input().split())
assert 1 <= R <= 20
assert 1 <= C <= 20

for r in range(R):
    print('*' * C)
```

Comment: "Is your code supposed to read the input and produce an output?" Yes.

Comment: I'm quite sure input and output are stdin and stdout. Not raw_input.

Comment: But how is that done in python?

Comment: have you tried searching 'python reading from stdin' on this very site?

Comment: Yes but I'm wondering where in the answer it reads the input

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you want me to explain the answer you yourself gave?

Comment: I didn't write the answer, I just don't understand where it takes in the input in the answer

Comment: it's the second line. Did you try looking up the mentioned functions and methods in the python documentation? Which part is not clear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if _ _name_ _ == '_ _main_ _':` This is not valid Python. It'll cause a `SyntaxError`.

`R, C = map(int, raw_input().split())` This is not correctly indented. Furthermore, `raw_input()` will be executed once, which means that it'll only consume one line of user input and then the `.split()` will actually split by space characters.

`assert 1 <= R <= 20` This is not really needed, as your logic does not have any solid requirement (The assignment is not telling you to disallow high numeric values)

`for r in range(R): print('*' * C)` This will do the trick.

---

As per my comments above, consider the following:

```
# If Python 2.x
# from __future__ import print_function

def stdin_readline():
    # If Python 2.x
    # return raw_input()

    # If Python 3.x
    return input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    R = int(stdin_readline())
    C = int(stdin_readline())
    for r in range(R):
        print('*' * C)
```

---

You can reduce this to just three lines:

```
# If Python 2.x
# from __future__ import print_function

def stdin_readline(*args):
    # If Python 2.x
    # return raw_input()

    # If Python 3.x
    return input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    R, C = map(int, map(stdin_readline, range(2)))
    output = map(print, ['*' * C for r in range(R)])

    # If Python 3.x
    list(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I'm confused at is does the user enter the input or is it read from a file?

Comment: @mij09 Well, it is read from the *standard input*. This doesn't mean that it comes from the user, but the code should not worry about this. `raw_input()` reads from standard input, whether this input comes from a file, from another process's output or from an user is irrelevant. From the point of view of your process, it's just a stream of characters.

Answer (score 0):

In python, every time you call `input`, you will get one "line" of the input. So, in this case they tell you, that 2 lines will be received, first R then C. So, you have to get two inputs in that order, wich means

```
R = input()
C = input()
```

Now, the thing about input, is you receive them as string, so if you want to use them as integers, you need to convert them to integers, so you do

```
R = int(input())
C = int(input())
```

And about the output, you are correct. If they tell you to generate an output, its just use the function `print`. So, the rest of the code is what you have at the end

```
for r in range(R):
print('*' * C)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much! One more thing, does the user have to enter the input themselves or can it be read from a file?